# reqest.getParameter() returns null for Select box in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I have the following code in a jsp file (on Adobe CQ) but, it returns null. Not sure why. I am expecting the out.println line to return 40 since it is the default selected value.

```
<select id="itemsperpage" name="itemsperpage">
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="40" selected>40</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
<option value="200">200</option>
</select>
<%
String itemsPerPage = request.getParameter("itemsperpage");
out.println("Items: " + itemsPerPage );
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code will  always return `null`. try to see `page source` after running your application. value of `Items` is always `null`.

try following code: (in this code I am sending a request on every time the value of combobox is changed)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body onload="form1.submit();">
<form action="#" name="form1">
<select id="itemsperpage" name="itemsperpage" onchange="submit();">
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="40" selected>40</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
<option value="200">200</option>
</select>
</form>
<%
String itemsPerPage = request.getParameter("itemsperpage");
out.println("Items: " + itemsPerPage );
%>
</body>
</html>
```

[Note: i will suggest you to not use `scriplets` in your jsp file, instead you can go for AJAX , JSTL etc. ]

Comment: It returns null when the page loads for the first time. After the page has finished loading, If I change the value in the select box to a new value, the new selected value is printed.

Comment: i have updated my code, now it will show first value from combobox when form loads

Comment: Thanks, I added a default value of 20 instead.

Comment: @Mandeep ok. you are welcome, but still try to avoid use of `scriplets` in your JSP

Comment: Also, How can i do this using JSTL?

Comment: I just wanted to suggest you that for sending the `request` to the `servlet` and `getting` the values from `servlet`, `AJAX` is a better way than using `scriplets` inside your `jsp`

Comment: Hello, is there any way to do this without submitting the form each time? Like, if I have many selects on the same page, then I wouldn't want them going to the next page each time. I'm getting nulls on each of the modified values on the next page.