# Changed select on jsp get null value in servlet

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I have a jsp page with a number of selects that are **populated using** **jQuery** i.e. they have the `<option>` tags, they just get it via a function. Each select has some 30 options each.

```
<form id="target" name="target" action="/project/myservlet" method="get">
<select class="myClass" id="sel1" name="sel1" ></select>
<select class="myClass" id="sel2" name="sel2"></select>
...
</form>
```

I received these values in my servlet using `request.getParameter("sel1")` but I'm getting null for the selects that are changed. As in, say I select values from the 2nd, 4th and 5th selects, then these selects get null values in the servlet. Others get the 0th value (default and unchanged) - which is okay.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728297/reqest-getparameter-returns-null-for-select-box-in-jsp) can help explain my question. I'm getting null in the next page when I modify the select.

According to this, if I use `onload` in select, it helps take the updated values to the next page for ONE select. But the problem is that I don't just have one select on the page. I want the updated values to go the next page without a page refresh/going to another page, unless submit for them is clicked. I think the request is not getting updated when the change takes place? Even the url in "get" doesn't get the changed selects.

There is no error as such, just that I am getting the values if the selects are unmodified (defaults). It sends the default values to the next page. When I select another option from the drop down, I get null on the servlet unless I use `onchange`to submit the form. But that doesn't work for me since I have many selects. I can't keep submitting the form and going to the next page on every select change.

EDIT:
If it helps, here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                $('select').change(function(){
                    var v = $(this).val();
                    $('select option[value="'+$(this).data('old-val')+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
                    $(this).data('old-val',v);
                    if(v != "0"){
                        $('select option[value="'+v+'"]').not(this).prop('disabled',true);
                    }
                });

                $('select').each(function(idx,select){   
                    var stateArray = ["Preference No. "+(idx+1),"Bill", "Sally", "Alice"];
                    $.each(stateArray, function(iIdx, iItem){  
                        $(select).append('<option value="'+iIdx+'">'+iItem+'</option>');
                    });
                });   

                $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
                    alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
                });

            });
```

EDIT 2: Servlet:
    public class Preference extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try {
             PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
             String sel  =  request.getParameter("sel1");
         }catch(Exception e){ }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you make your question more clearer?

Comment: do you use ajax request to send data or form submit, can you elaborate more on how you send data??

Comment: @SpringLearner: Try reading it now.

Comment: you do not have option tag and so there wont be any drop down

Comment: I do have them. The selects are populated using jQuery. Each select gets 30 options each, so I populated them using a function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<option>` tags into your `<select>` tags.

Each `<option>` must have `value` attribute like this:

`<option value="3">Apple</option>`

Value from the `value` attribute of the selected option will be value of your `<select>`. You will get it on server-side by `name` as usual.

Comment: The options are getting populated using jQuery. Its a separate function in `<script>...</script>`. All the selects have options. Some 30 each.

Comment: So, you need to provide complete code. Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: I am getting the values if the selects are unmodified. It sends the default values to the next page. When I select another option from the drop down, I get null on the servlet

Comment: It hard to determine exact moment error happen. So, please just copy resulting html from developer tools in browser and check for errors in browser console.

Comment: I'm just probably missing how to take the values of updated selects on the next page. Its taking the non-changed values to the servlet just fine.

Comment: Selected `<option>` should have `selected` attribute: `<option value="4" selected="selected">Apple</option>`.

Comment: @user2816215 What server-side code you using to get the values from `<option>`?

Comment: @user2816215 It's very hard to say what's wrong. You need to debug your server-side code, watch values of the variables. Are you sure that you dealing with original request object in method you provided? I'm not sure what is happening. And there is another question: how you determine that you do not getting a value? I offer you: try to make very simple example without JQuery on client-side and many chained methods on server-side. Just simple request handler to understand how it works.

Comment: Okay, let me try that.

Comment: You could add me in skype (find it in my profile) and show your screen. We could try to debug it together.

Comment: I found the answer. The selects were getting disabled in my jquery. And disabled selects are not carried forward.

Answer (score 0):

The selected options were disabled from all the select elements in my jQuery. I had to modify the jQuery a little. Disabled elements are not carried forward in a form. On modifying the jQuery to not disable the options, the problem was resolved. Had to take a bit of a help to recognize and correct that.